# Take multiple columns of one dataframe to create another dataframe of two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe of 145 columns, one column is variable A and the rest are subsets of variable B. What I want is a new dataframe of two columns, A and B. I want to make sure all the B values in the new dataframe have the corresponding A values.

A simplified example of 'original' dataframe:

```
   A  B1  B2
0  1   6  11
1  2   7  12
2  3   8  13
3  4   9  14
4  5  10  15
```

And what I would like to achieve:

```
   A   B
0  1   6
1  2   7
2  3   8
3  4   9
4  5  10
5  1  11
6  2  12
7  3  13
8  4  14
9  5  15
```

I have tried to do it like this but have manage to only get the equivalent of B1 and A, the rest vanishes.

```
original_data = data[1:145]

filtered_data = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A', 'B'])

columns = list(original_data)

for values in columns:
    for row in pressure_data:
        filtered_data["B"] = original_data[values]
        filtered_data["A"] = data['A']
```

I'd appreciate any tips/advice! Many thanks.

Comment: It's just `df.melt('A', value_name='B').drop('variable', 1)`

Comment: Or wide_to_long :)  `pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames='B', i='A', j='j').reset_index().`

Comment: or stack... `df.set_index('A').stack().droplevel(1).reset_index(name='B')`

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help.